# javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression missing documentation

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6

From the rather sparse javadocs:

> See EJB specification for the full timer expression syntax.

There's no link, and no further clue where to find this "full syntax". Does anybody know what they're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

see [ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318) §18.2.4 about `Timer` I think

Comment: Actually, it is section 18.2.1 that discusses calendar-based timer expressions.